# python why does import fail when executed by bash or sh

Tags: python, bash

This is weird can someone explain. Here is a python program say called tp.py

```
!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print("here tis")
```

If i run this so
./tp.py
or
python tp.py

it works

If I try
bash ./tp.py
or sh ./tp.py

It fail on import sys

I am mostly interested because a software vendor's README says to use the sh ./tp.py version and I'd like to point out the error and the reason why it fails. I don't understand the reason why.

Comment: Can you post the error message? Otherwise my best guess is that bash and sh aren't finding python3 to run the program with.

Comment: run output of `sh "which  python"`  and `which  python` most probably python is not set in subshell

Comment: The shebang line (first line in the script file) needs to start with `#!`, not just `!`. Is it actually missing the hash sign?

Comment: Apologies I thought id edited this better. The code begin with #!/usr/bin/env python3.  I was working on Raspberry 
Pi with this problem. On Ubuntu with bash or sh I get
bash ./tp.py
import-im6.q16: not authorized `sys' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
./tp.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `"here tis"'
./tp.py: line 3: `print("here tis")'
The program works using ./tp.py or python tp.py or python3 tp.py
ry it for yourselves